# How can i display the count in a better way?

Tags: d3.js

I have displayed the count of the bar graphs here. But when the value in the dataset of the bar is 0, it displays 0 and disrupts the y label. i want to display the values appropriately and only when it's non zero. The values shouldnot mess with the axes. How can i do that?

Here is the working fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/84hp8m6p/1/

Here's what i am using to append text

```
    groups.selectAll('.bartext')
   .data(function(d) {
   return d;
   })
   .enter()
   .append("text")
   .attr("class", "bartext")
   .attr("text-anchor", "end")
   .attr("fill", "black")
   .attr('x', function(d) {
   return xScale(d.x0) + xScale(d.x);
   })
  .attr('y', function(d, i) {
   return yScale(d.y) + yScale.rangeBand() / 2;
   })
  .text(function(d) {
   return d.x;
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to show only values greater than zero (or any other value):

```
.text(function(d) {
    return (d.x > 0) ? d.x : "";
});
```

Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1gx3kcz4/

Comment: Hey that worked. I didn't think of that...was trying all bad solution...could you help me in displaying the values at the end of rects too?

Comment: Just remove the `text-anchor` attribute: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/euc6q9yr/